# Application of uniform boundedness (Banach-Steinhaus) principle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

$\DeclareMathOperator{\loc}{\mathrm{loc}}$This is from Lemarié-Rieusset's book *"The Navier-Stokes problem in the 21st century"*, from the proof of a result about stationary solutions to Navier-Stokes (Theorem 16.2). There's a step where he uses the uniform boundedness theorem in a way that I can't comprehend. I will outline the relevant part of the proof and also add some steps that he doesn't explicitly give.

We're considering functions parameterized by $R>0$, $u_R:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\|u_R\|_{\dot{H^1}}$ is bounded uniformly in $R$. Thus, for every $$\phi\in \mathcal{D}=\{\text{smooth, compactly supported functions in }\mathbb{R}^3\},$$ we have
$$\sup_{R}\|\phi u_R\|_{H^1}<\infty.$$
For any choice of test function $\phi$, by Rellich Kondrachov, we can extract a subsequence $R_k\to \infty$ such that $\phi u_{R_k}$ converges in $L^p$ for $p\in[1,6)$. Taking as test functions a sequence of functions $\phi_N\in \mathcal D$ that approximate the constant function $1$ in the limit $N\to\infty$, we obtain, via a diagonlization argument, a subsequence of $R_k$, which we continue to call $R_k$, such that $u_{R_k}$ converges to some function $u$ in $L^p_{\loc}$.  (That is, we have a $3\epsilon$ argument: we have that $\phi_Nu_{R_k}$ converges as $R_k\to \infty$ to some function $u_N$ in $L^p_{\loc}$, then we show that $u_N$ form a Cauchy sequence in $L^p_{\loc}$. On the other hand, $u_{R_k}$ can be approximated by $\phi_N u_{R_k}$.).

Then, it is claimed that "by Banach-Steinhaus" (i.e. uniformed bounded principle), we have $u\in \dot {H^1}$.

I simply don't see in what way Banach-Steinhaus was used to reach such a conclusion. The way I see it, we started with a sequence $u_R$ which we know a priori to be bounded in $\dot H^1$, uniformly in $R$. From this, a subsequence $u_{R_k}$ has been extracted such that $u_{R_k}\to u$. The latter convergence, as far as I can see is only in $L^p_{\loc}$ for $p<6$. Of course, if this convergence were to hold in $\dot{H^1}$, then by definition, $u\in\dot{H^1}$, and no appeal to Banach-Steinhaus is needed. So I'm assuming that indeed we only have convergence in the aforementioned local $L^p$ spaces. But by some separate reasoning involving Banach Steinhaus, we are somehow able to conclude that $u$ nonetheless is in $\dot{H^1}$... how is this done??

Comment: Should it maybe be "$\sup_R \|\phi u_R\|_{\dot{H}^1} < \infty$", so with the homogeneous Sobolev (= gradient) norm? Also, what properties of $\dot{H}^1$ are assumed at the point in the book? For instance, if I see it correctly, if one uses the Sobolev embedding and reflexivity for $\dot{H}^1$, that should do it. (Extract weakly convergent subsequence of $u_R$, use Sobolev embeding, then the weak limit in $\dot{H}^1$ must coincide with $u$ in, say, $L^2_{loc}$.) The UBP argument eludes me, though.

Comment: The statement $\sup_{R}||\phi u_R||_{{H^1}}<\infty$ holds as well because $u_R\in \dot{H^1}$ and $\phi$ has compact support so their product is in $H^1$.

Comment: @Fozz what about $u_R=R$ (constant function) which is bounded in $\dot{H}^1$ and for which $\sup_R ||\phi u_R||_{H^1} = \infty$ as soon as $\phi \neq 0$ ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think the space $\dot{H^1}$ is defined in terms of equivalence classes where functions that differ by polynomials are identified. In particular, all constant functions are equivalent to the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a satisfactory answer，should be a comment, but I do not have the reputation to write comment, so I write it here.

1. $u_R$ is uniformly bounded,
   \begin{equation*}
   \left\|\vec{u}_{R}\right\|_{\dot{H}^{1}} \leq \frac{1}{\nu}\|\vec{f}\|_{\dot{H}^{-1}}
   \end{equation*}
   so a weak limit $u$ of $u_R$ (distribution sense) exist, this can be figure out by take diagonal subsequence of a sequence, further more, in general case the weak limit $u$ is a continuous linear functional defined on $D$ and can not extend to $H^{-1}$ still bounded(or continue), if it can extend as a continuous linear functional on $C^{\infty} \subset H^{1} \subset H^{-1}$, then it is conincide with a $\hat u\in H^1$ and belong to $H^{1}$.

2.by rellich theorem, we can figure out
\begin{equation*}
H^{1}(R^3)=W^{1, 1}(R^3) \subset \subset L^{q}(R^3) \text { for } 1 \leq q<6 
\end{equation*}
So by use the method of taking diagonal subsequence of a sequence, we can find a $u$,
$$u_{R_k} \longrightarrow u,\ in \ L^q(R^3),\ \forall 1\leq q<6 $$

3. a weak limit of a sequence if exist then it is unique, so by take subsequence of process of 1,2. we can find a subsequence $u_{R_k}$, $u$ is the weak limit of $u_{R_k}$, so $u$ satisfied the equation,
   \begin{equation*}
   \nu \Delta \vec{u}+\vec{f}-\operatorname{div}(\vec{u} \otimes \vec{u})=\vec{\nabla} p
   \end{equation*}
   in distribution sense, and at the same time $u\in L^{q}(R^3), \forall 1\leq q<6 $

4.Now, the problem is can we go further to get $u\in H^{1}$, in general this is not true for bound sequence $\left\|\vec{u}_{R}\right\|_{\dot{H}^{1}} \leq M$, but when $u_R$ is come from some approximation of a differential equation, this is in general true, if not blow up. I do not know how to firgue out this special one, but it seem the general method is use the regularity we already get, i.e. $u\in L^q(R^3), \forall 1\leq q<6$ into the distribution equation, i.e. \begin{equation*}
\nu \Delta \vec{u}+\vec{f}-\operatorname{div}(\vec{u} \otimes \vec{u})=\vec{\nabla} p
\end{equation*}
if change the equation to $\Delta u+u^2=f, f\in L^2(R^n)$, then by the previous argument we can show a suitable limit $u=lim_{k}u_k$ satisfied $u\in L^{q}(R^n), \forall 1\leq q<6$, and then as distribution $\Delta u=f-u^2 \in L^{2}(R^n)$, and then $u\in H^{2,2}(R^3)$, there should be a similar method to gain the information that $u= lim u_{R_k}$ is in $H^1$.

Comment: The space $\dot{H^1}$ is the space of distributions $f$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\xi|^2|\mathcal{F}f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty$ (here $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform). Basically, it's the space of distributions whose gradient is in $L^2$.

Comment: Are you viewing $u_R$ as a linear operator from $\dot{H^1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ ($\phi\mapsto\int\phi u_R\,dx$) or from $\dot{H^1}$ to $H^1$ ($\phi\mapsto \phi u_R$)?

Comment: from $\dot H^1 \to R$, test function space is dense in $\dot H^1$, so there is a natural extension to make $u_R$ to be a linear operator on $\dot H^1$

Comment: For $\phi\in\mathcal D$, the map $\phi\mapsto\int\phi u_R\,dx$ IS a linear operator, but how do we know it's continuous with respect to $\dot{H^1}$? I guess what I mean is, if we approximate $\phi\in \dot{H^1}$ by $\phi_k\in\mathcal D$ in the space $\dot{H^1}$, how does it follow that $\int \phi_k u_R\,dx\to\int\phi u_R\,dx$ as well?

Comment: @Fozz, in fact in your case because of priori estimate and application of Leray–Schauder principle we can prove $u_{R} \in \dot{H}^{1}$, so the argument can all live in $\dot{H}^{1} \subset H^
{-1}$ and the limit is also in $\dot{H}^{1}$

Comment: @Fozz, if the underly space is separable, there is $R^3$ of course it is. then the test function space is dense in distribution, and we can use the limit to define the action of $u_{R}$ on a general distribution $\phi$ by $\int \phi_{k} u_{R} d x \rightarrow \int \phi u_{R} d x$ where $ \phi_{k}$ is a sequence of function weak converage to $\phi$ in distribution, we only need to prove it is well-defined(do not rely on the choice of sequence) and it is linear, this is easy.

Comment: we can use convolution of $\phi$ with a approximation to identity or use step function to approximate and then convolution with some approximation to identity(there are some other way to prove this of course) to prove testfuntion is dense in distribution if the underly space is separable.